# Visual Studio Quick Fix

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Есть ли в студии аналог Quick Fix из эклипса (Ctrl+1)?

Answer (score 1):

В Visual Studio есть смарт-теги <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Если класса MyClass не существует, VS предложит его создать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоже самое с методом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И с переменными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так далее.

Comment: А для исправления ошибок?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Это как раз и исправляет ошибки. В примере выше класса MyClass не существует, и VS предлагает сгенерировать его. Я попробовал добавить еще несколько примеров.