# Автоподстановка типа

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Можно ли в студии написать `a = 2`, что-то нажать и получить `int a = 2`?

Comment: А если на деле a нужен double? Нет уж, сам пиши тип у переменной.

Comment: @Vesper тогда ручками. В случае со строкой/другими типами все однозначно.

Comment: Со строкой тоже не вполне однозначно. А вдруг программист хотел `object` или `IEnumerable<char>`?

Comment: @VladD если не однозначно - то ручками, как я уже написал.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Я просто к тому, что со строкой не так всё однозначно.

Comment: @VladD ну я и не говорил, что все однозначно. Например, может понадобиться, чтобы переменная a = new ArrayList() имела тип List, а не ArrayList и т.д. Хорошо бы, чтобы IDE и это могла подсказать.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Просто `List` есть только в Java, ЕМНИП. В C# non-generic `ArrayList` и `List<T>`.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: (хотя это мелочи, да)

Comment: @VladD List<T> и в жавке есть. Главное, понятно, что я имею в виду - интерфейсы/их предки и предки класса создаваемого объекта.

Answer (score 3):

В C# есть `var`:

```
var a = 2;
```

Определит типа `a` автоматическим образом. При наведении курсора на `var`, печатает:

> struct System.Int32

Но не знаю, существует ли укороченный путь вставить `var`.

Comment: Во-первых это, во-вторых не всегда можно или хочется его иметь. В эклипсе можно было написать `int a = "asd";`, нажать Ctrl+1 и получить коррекцию `String a = "asd";`

Comment: Не понял, во-первых это что?

Comment: "Но не знаю, существует ли укороченный путь вставить var."

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно использовать сторонний плагин для студии, например [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (платный).

Щелкаем по лампочке слева от строки или жмем <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Подсказка при создании переменной]
[image: Подсказка при неправильном типе переменной или значения]

Comment: А без решарпера она такого не умеет? Классы-то создавать предлагает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Студия, конечно, умеет делать некоторые вещи сама (я затрагивал некоторые моменты в другом вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438629/185673), но в данном случае она ничего не предлагает.

Comment: По какой комбинации это вылазит?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Alt + Enter